# WordPress Rewrite Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

Example Code:

```
function flush_rewrite_rules()
{
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
function activate()
{
    global $wp_rewrite;
    createRewriteRules( $wp_rewrite );
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
function createRewriteRules( $rewrite )
{
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $new_rules = array( 'option/(.+)' => 'index.php?option=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) );
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules; // ERROR HERE............
    return $wp_rewrite;
}
add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', createRewriteRules );
register_activation_hook( file, activate );
```

Sometimes gives Fatal error: Unsupported operand types, but activates the plugin and doesn't stop it from working...  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably either $new_rules or $wp_rewrite->rules is not an array at the moment you want to combine them.

You could add a test to see if they are arrays, and if not, initialize them as an empty array.

(Addition:
Why pass $rewrite as an argument, when you use a global to get the original variable?)

Comment: Beat me by five seconds. :) Welcome to SO.

Comment: Thanks! Took me some time to find an unanswered question ;)

Comment: I passed it as an argument to test something, and didn't change it back in the example code provided.

Comment: wp_rewrite->rules is [rules] => 

Should I test like this? 

if ($wp_rewrite->rules == '') $wp_rewrite->rules = array();

I'm not 100% sure on the correct way of doing this. 
Thanks
-Brad

Comment: You can use is_array() to check if a variable is an array.

So it would be:
if (!is_array($wp_rewrite->rules)){ $wp_rewrite->rules = array(); }